# Filtering and combining data in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array:

```
{"Items":[
{"folder":"Test","number":"11"},
{"folder":"Test","number":"10"},
{"folder":"Test1","number":"130"},
{"folder":"Test1","number":"100"},
{"folder":"Test2","number":""},
{"folder":"Test2","number":"200"}
]}
```

Tell me I need to make it so that the **folder** is unique, and write its values in **number** separated by commas?

```
{"Items":[
{"folder":"Test","number":"11, 10"},
{"folder":"Test1","number":"130, 100"},
{"folder":"Test2","number":"200"}
]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `GroupBy` to group by folder and `String.Join()` to concatenate numbers, like :

```
var result = Items
    .GroupBy(x => x.folder)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        folder = x.Key,
        number = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.number).Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z)))
    }).ToList();
```

Test in dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDvSmc